# Changing project name did not change competely

Tags: xcode, macos

So, I changed the project name.  Xcode made some changes but not all (Top image).  How do you go about to make the change for the rest (last two images)?

[image: Image Old3]

[image: Image Old1]

[image: Image Old2]

Comment: How did you change the project name?

Comment: @zaph:  From the top image, taping the project name at the upper left most and changed the name.

Comment: Edit `MainWindow.xib`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Xcode rename capabilities, to get the documentation right-click on the target name, here is how it looks to get to the help:

[image]

Here is a portion of the help:

[image]

Comment: I created a new app just to test this way.  It has the same result.